# How to pass a parameter to a scenario in Yii?

Tags: yii

How to pass `$id` to search scenario? Maybe in model look like this, so I can call like in controller like:

```
$model = new job('search',$id);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can define scenario with parameter but that is included within the class constructor of the model

```
$model = new Job('search'); // creating a model with scenario search
```

If you wish to include more parameters, then you need to use `createComponent` -remember, all is a component

```
$model = Yii::createComponent(array('class'=>'Job','scenario'=>'search'));
```

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are trying to do a search. Search is one thing, a "scenario" is something else.

Scenarios are used in validation rules in order to be able to validate the same model in multiple ways depending from where you're inserting/adding OR searching data.

There's also a scenario called 'search' that is used by the model's `search()` method, but I tell you why:

There are a couple of ways to search for something in your database using Yii, I will mention two:

**1) By using ClassName::model()->findCommandHere**

And there are a couple of them:

```
ClassName::model()->findByPk($id);
ClassName::model()->findAll("id=$id");
ClassName::model()->findByAttributes(array('id'=>$id));
```

And so on, more here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#reading-record

**2) By using the model's search() method**

This way of finding data is mostly used for easily creating search pages and in combination with data grids.

If you generate CRUD code with the GII code generation tool it will generate all the parts for you, but I will explain each part how it works.

This code is from the blog demo found in Yii files:

In controller it defines a `$model` using Post class and 'search' as scenario.

```
$model=new Post('search');
if(isset($_GET['Post']))  // <- checks if there are search params in the URL
    $model->attributes=$_GET['Post']; // <- assigns all search params masively to the model (later you'll see why)
$this->render('admin',array(
    'model'=>$model,
));
```

The 'search' scenario here tells Yii what validation rules to use when assigning search parameters directly from `$_GET` (URL).

You can see that the params are assigned massively to reduce code written but `$model->attributes=$_GET['Post']` it is the same as doing:

```
$model->title=$_GET['Post']['title'];
$model->status=$_GET['Post']['status'];
```

In the Post model you can find the validation rules for the search scenario. Tells Yii that it is safe to assign title and status fields in order to later use them in the search.

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // ... //

        array('title, status', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'), 
    );
}
```

Then also in the Post model you can see the `search()` method that will actually be used to get the data:

```
public function search()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('title',$this->title,true);

    $criteria->compare('status',$this->status);

    return new CActiveDataProvider('Post', array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'status, update_time DESC',
        ),
    ));
}
```

The search method creates a "criteria" and applies the desired way of filtering using the values you have previously assigned to this model. See the `$this->title` it comes from the `$model->attributes=$_GET['Post']` you used in the controller.

The criteria can be used directly on the model, such as `Post::model()->findAll($criteria)`, but in this case the `search()` method uses something different, a "data provider".

The data provider is a good thing because it provides you a lot of tools in one place, it returns you the data, but also the pagination, and the sorting, so you don't have to manually define more code for that purposes (`CPagination`, `CSort`).

Finally, in the view admin.php in this case it will display the results using a grid view:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name'=>'title',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->title), $data->url)'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'status',
            'value'=>'Lookup::item("PostStatus",$data->status)',
            'filter'=>Lookup::items('PostStatus'),
        ),

    ),
));
```

Now you can see that in the configuration of the grid it passes `$model->search()` method as the `dataProvider` that the grid should use.

Now the grid can access the rest of the `dataProvider` elements such as sort, pagination and display them on the page.

If you did not want to use the `CGridView` because it's a very basic table and you want to create your own html markup, you can also retrieve the `dataProvider` and its components one by one and place them in your HTML code and display data as you want:

```
$dataProvider=$model->search(); // get the dataprovider from search method
$models=$dataProvider->getData(); // actually get the data (rows) and assign them to a $models variable that you can put in a foreach loop

// show pagination somewhere
$this->widget('CLinkPager', array(
              'pages' => $dataProvider->pagination,
          ));

// create sort links
echo $dataProvider->sort->link('title', 'Title');
```

So I hope it solves some of your doubts on how to use Yii for displaying/searching data.

I suggest you read the official manual: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/index

I also suggest to look at the API and so search there all the Yii components to see what methods and params they have: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/

Also exploring the framework codebase manually is quite a good way to learn. If you don't know how `CActiveDataProvider` works, then find the `CActiveDataProvider` class file in the code and you'll see all the methods and properties that it uses, so do this for everything you don't understand how it works.

Also for beginners I recommend using a good IDE that auto-completes code and allows you to Ctrl+Click a class name and it will locate the original file where it was defined. I use NetBeans for PHP and after creating a project I add Yii framework files to the project's include paths that way NetBeans knows how to find the framework files for auto-complete and for ctrl+click.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will simply do the job without needing any scenario

```
$model = new job;   
$model->search($id);
```

But If I have failed to understand your problem then you can also try this

```
$model = new job('search');
$model->search($id);
```

Comment: I think in Yii1 $model->search() method generated by Gii code generation tool takes no parameters. You should first instanciate the class with 'search' scenario, then assign a value to the id property, and then run search() that will return you the CActiveDataProvider.

Comment: @AlexandruTrandafirCatalin and where is this written that you can not modify the DEFAULT SEARCH method generated by YII. You can take any parameter you want as per your needs. Please do not downvote for such a pity reason. Search for a better one

Comment: you are right that you can modify the default search method generated by Yii, but I doubt based on this user's experience that he would understand your answer. I think he would take for granted that search() method works by default by passing a $id parameter. That's why I did the downvote, also any new Yii users reaching this post would end up thinking the same, you could include some note about the search() function so nobody gets confused.

Answer (score 1):

Think of scenarios as a special variable that you can use in the model.

```
$userModel = new User("register");
$userModel->setId = 10;
```

which is the same

```
$userModel = new User();
$userModel->scenario = 10
$userModel->setId = 10;
```

And in your model

```
class Manufacturer extends CActiveRecord
{
        // :
   if ($this->scenario == 'register')  ...
        // :

}
```